# Is detecting bullet point types used and their order to automatically indent text based on bullet point hierarchy possible with Regexes?

Tags: javascript, parsing, scripting, formatting

I am parsing different chunks of PDF text filled with different types of bullet points, This text is fairly difficult to read due to the lack of indentation. It also sometimes loses or adds extra line breaks.

I wanted to write a script that removes extra line breaks before using 10-20 different bullet point regexes to track which bullet points show up and in what order before automatically applying 1 indent to which ever type of bullet point shows up first, two to the next, then three and so on and so forth. It also adds a preceding line break to ensure each bullet point is on a new line.

Typical bullet points include ones using a combination of the following symbols

1. Capital Leets
2. Lower Case Letters
3. Roman Numerals
4. Numbers
5. • or " o "

And can be wrapped with

- ")" at the end
- "-" at the end, possibly with a space in between
- "(" and ")" at the start and end
- "." at the end

I wrote a script with 20 regexes for all of these options that

- Tracks the order in which these regexes match with different sections of the document
- Adds regexes to an array based on this order
- Iterates through these regexes replacing each matched element with "\n" + element
- Applies a different number of indents based on the Regexes position in the array

Unfortunately I found that it breaks down pretty quickly due to a lot of false positives. I was wondering if there is a better way to do this or a prebuilt library/function I can use?

Comment: This is a beast, I think you should just test for a prefix after splitting on each new line, the prefix, and replace it with a bullet point or number/letter scheme

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This is not 100% the answer to your question as that would require a heap of code, just something you may be able to build on to solve this tricky problem.

As mentioned above, if I were you, I would just replace all the bullets / letters with you own scheme. If you want to use bullets/letters based on the first one you find, you would need to create another variable, set it on the first true when you find a sentence with a prefix, and then based on that type, add in the bullets.

```js
let sentence = `a) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi pulvinar viverra feugiat. Aliquam in metus nec tortor porttitor posuere. Aliquam id ligula tincidunt, ullamcorper libero vitae, iaculis tortor. Cras venenatis ullamcorper sapien, id porttitor mi finibus et. Integer faucibus dapibus justo eu ornare. Aenean sit amet lacus scelerisque ex posuere vestibulum et ut sapien. Donec vitae orci id leo auctor dignissim.

1. Nam pellentesque neque et ipsum feugiat tempus. Ut lobortis risus non sem iaculis, sed efficitur sapien lobortis. Curabitur tempus ultrices maximus. Vestibulum ullamcorper elit lorem, pulvinar maximus ligula ultricies ac. Mauris feugiat arcu non odio elementum, sit amet luctus sem convallis. Maecenas condimentum nulla turpis, id vestibulum leo porta id. Proin et pretium mauris. Nam eu metus non velit ullamcorper bibendum. Aenean nec purus consequat, pharetra libero vitae, gravida dolor. In a felis sodales, tincidunt justo non, vulputate orci. Morbi interdum erat ante, vel imperdiet lectus condimentum non. Morbi sed mattis felis, consectetur dictum sapien. Nulla vestibulum blandit facilisis.
b) In eget nunc ac quam rutrum rhoncus. Sed tempor, est quis tincidunt sollicitudin, enim nibh aliquet turpis, id interdum orci purus eget orci. Suspendisse vestibulum orci quis rutrum bibendum. In ligula orci, dapibus in vehicula id, varius molestie ante. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam quis sollicitudin leo, et porta urna. Maecenas vitae feugiat elit.
`

const testForPrefix = (sentence) => {
  // Return if a letter is followed by a ')'
  if (/^[A-Z]+[)]/i.test(sentence)) return true;
    return !/^[A-Z]/i.test(sentence);
};

const removePrefix = (sentence) => {
  while (testForPrefix(sentence) && sentence.length > 0) {
    sentence = sentence.substring(1);
  }
  return sentence;
};

sentence
  .split('\n') // split on each new line
  .filter((line) => line.length) // filter out lines with no length
  .map((line, i) => {
    // Test and remove the prefix.
    console.log(`. ${removePrefix(line)}`);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately the bullet points need to be preserved as they contain valid required information such as 1. Must meet points A., B. and C. and then  A  might say Must meet sub-bullets i, ii and iii. So while I'd love to strip all bullets out, I can't.